How do I override the "being autocompleted" input color in Microsoft Edge?
I have a css file that specifies
* {
  color: white
}

and then has various styles for inputs to override this with a black font color. However, while an input is being autofilled by Edge, the "matched characters" inside the input revert to the wildcard color, rendering them invisible on the white background.
See the image below, the arrow in the image below points to four white characters being rendered invisibly, followed by the letters "an"

None of the autofill-related CSS styles seems to have any effect. The problem only occurs in Edge, Chrome doesn't have this behaviour. It also seems to be a change that has been introduced recent-ish.
Is there any specific selector to specify the color of this text in Edge? As a workaround I can set the wildcard color selector to black, but that is a non-trivial change to the css.

For Edge, use -webkit-text-fill-color to target the fill color of the text. (It looks really like a bug to me as the text-fill-color should default to currentcolor if not being set according to the spec. Unlike :autofill's color, it's not default to any value in the UA style as well.)


* {
  color: white
}

label {
  color: black;
}

input {
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
}
<form>
  <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
  <input autocomplete="given-name" id="firstName">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Both the clear answer and the confirmation that it seems to be a bug.
